# CakePHP, Username Regex

Tags: regex, cakephp

Well i'm currently trying to use a regex, but it didn't do what i want.

It's a username regex validation :

```
var $validate = array(
            'nom' => array(
                'regex_nom' => array(
                    'rule'      => '/^[A-Za-zÉÈÊËÜÛÎÔÄÏÖÄÇéèëêüûçîôâïöäa]+$/',
                    'message'   => 'Nom incorrect.'
                )
            )
        );
```

Well i don't think it's needed to explain what i want, but the problem is that when i enter, for instance : Tesédsf it didn't match and i dunno why...

Comment: Does it work if you remove the e-acute? Perhaps the UTF-8 regex `/^\p{Alpha}*$/` works in PHP?

Comment: Oh god, you find it !

It was only because my file were not saved in UTF8, Thx a lot !

Comment: Yes, those wonderful windows codepages...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this regexp `/^\p{L}+$/u`. It checks for words in every language in UTF-8 string.

Answer (score 2):

You need the `/u` modifier to match UTF-8 strings. In addition the Unicode properties appear to work, so you could write

```
'rule'      => '/^\p{Alpha}+$/u',
```

Comment: missing a star there? '/^\p{Alpha}*$/u'

Comment: @Timothy: Yes, Thank you. A plus sign to match the OP's code. That has remained unnoticed for three and a half years!

Answer (score 0):

Could be an encoding issue. Try:

```
'rule' => '/^\p{L&}+$/'
```